# How can I restart Firefox from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, firefox

How can I restart Firefox from the command-line and restore the previous state completely (or as much as possible) after restart? Sure, I can do something like `killall firefox; firefox`, but that would not restore the session.

Answer (score 5):

You can set Firefox to open with the previously open windows & tabs. It should  be under Preferences -> General -> "When Firefox starts". Set that to "Show my windows and tabs from last time":

[image]

You should now be able to restart `firefox` with `killall firefox; firefox &` and have the same session.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to do a setting in firefox before you restart it from command line. Go to:

```
   Prefrences->General->When Firefox starts
```

and select :

```
   Show my windows and tabs from last time
```

then from the command line , restart it the way you like ( may be `killall firefox; firefox&`) and you ll get the desired result.

For more advance tuning about session restore you can type `about:config` in address bar and search for session or restore to change it.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1089103#answer-794586

Comment: The 'show my windows and tabs from last time' setting has been renamed to 'open previous windows and tabs'  (about:preferences#general)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to accomplish this.  The closest thing to it would actually be using the Firefox Console (`Shift` + `F2`) and typing in `restart`.

[image: Firefox Console restart function]

Aside from that, one could install an Addon or take @terdon's [advice in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252539/27776) and change Firefox Preferences to "**Show my windows and tabs from last time**" *When Firefox starts* and "restarting" with

```
$ killall firefox; sleep 1; firefox &
```

UPDATE: The "gcli" was [removed from firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1222635) in 2018.  Therefore, the "Shift+F2" shortcut no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

If you desire to restart Firefox with two or more profiles, this Bash script appears to work consistently:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall -s SIGTERM firefox; sleep 60
firefox -P "user" &
firefox -P "default settings" &
```

Replace the quoted profile names with your own (see `about:profiles`). Use the `-foreground` [flag](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions) to control which windows appears on top, if desired.

As noted by the other answers, enable the 'open previous windows and tabs' setting in the preferences (`about:preferences#general`)

<sub>The value in `sleep 60` (seconds) can potentially be lowered.</sub>

Comment: At 60 seconds, I've still got the "Firefox is still running" error when the script starts Firefox after `sleep`. Ryzen 5700G, 32GB DDR4 RAM.

Comment: Regarding cron, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700698/a-basic-bash-script-to-start-a-gui-program-works-partially-in-cron

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, edit advanced settings via `about:config`, search for  `resume` and set the `browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once` flag to `true`, then exit.

Here's documentation on the flag:
https://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once